# Flags in sub-Makefile.am

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, static-libraries, autotools

I have a `C` project with the following structure with 1 target (binary final product)

```
main.c
configure.in
configure
Makefile.am
Makefile.in
folder-1
..Makefile.am
..Makefile.in
..<static library files .c files>
..<static library files .h files>
folder-2
<some .c files>
<some .h files>
...
...
```

I am aware how to configure and compile my project with `Autotools`. In regard to my library of `folder-1`: i am often changing files in that library with different debug levels by defining a flag called DMYDEBUG.

Compilation time for the whole project takes a while and by now, i am able to change the flag by 
(1) modifiying the top-level `configure.in` file:

```
CCONFIGFLAGS="${CCONFIGFLAGS} -DSF_BIGENDIAN -DMYDEBUG=3"
```

(2) running `make clean`
(3) regenerating `configure` from the edited `configure.in` where i modify DMYDEBUG 
(3) running `./configure` on top level 
(4) running `make`

only this way the wished effect is taking places. Is there a better way to modify `DMYDEBUG` (which is only relevant to the static library in `folder-1`) without having to recompile the whole project each time?

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, it's terrible that you modify your `configure.in` to change the flag value.  It would be much better to make `configure` recognize a custom argument that conveys the information, such as `--with-debug-level=x`.  The `AC_ARG_WITH()` macro serves this purpose.

However, if you have to reconfigure the project (re-run `./configure`, with or without rebuilding it first) to change the flag, then changing the flag will always require a full rebuild.  For more narrowly-scoped rebuilding, you need to rely on `make` detecting the flag modification and re-building the affected targets.

`make` recognizes only file-level dependencies, so that strategy relies on you putting the macro definition in a header file, which the files that use it `#include`.  Since you're using Automake, you can rely on your build system to recognize header dependencies automatically, but you may need to perform one clean build to bootstrap that.